# Unusual behaviour in loaded event in Android

Tags: android, ios, angular, nativescript

I wonder if you can help me with the following. I am trying to track down on what tab/page a user has clicked at any point. I am using a (loaded) event to track down what page I land on. My code works like a charm on iOS, but on Android all the event calls are plain weird either they run in the same time, or not at all. Any ideas for this behaviour? Thanks.

For the Tab1 page:

on my tab1.html file

```
<StackLayout (loaded)="onTab1ViewLoaded()">
...
</StackLayout>
```

on the tab1.ts file

```
onTab1ViewLoaded() {
console.log("Tab1 loaded");
}
```

Similar code for the rest 3 tabs.

As a reminder this code works just fine in iOS, but in Android clicking on tab2 or tab3 I see all three events triggered in the console log. And sometimes, no console log events at all. Any ideas why? Thanks.

UPDATE

The tab.html page

```
<TabView androidOffscreenTabLimit="0" androidTabsPosition="bottom" (selectedIndexChanged)="onSelectedIndexChanged($event)">    

    <page-router-outlet *tabItem="{title: 'Tab1'}" name="Tab1">
    </page-router-outlet>

    <page-router-outlet *tabItem="{title: 'Tab2'}" name="Tab2">
    </page-router-outlet>

    <page-router-outlet *tabItem="{title: 'Tab3'}" name="Tab3"> 
    </page-router-outlet>

</TabView>
```

The tab.ts page

```
onSelectedIndexChanged(args) {
        if (args.newIndex != args.oldIndex) {
            console.log(args.newIndex);            
        }
    }
```

Any idea how to find out on what tab is on when navigating the TabView?

Answer (score 0):

Tab on Android is preloaded to support swipe to next tab, if you want to load it one by one you can use androidOffscreenTabLimit="0" on TabView, more information in here: 
https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/ng-ui-widgets/tab-view

But i recommend you use ngModel or selectedIndexChanged property to track down page.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My TabView is already using androidOffscreenTabLimit="0" but looks like the androidTabsPosition="bottom" cancels off the preloading of all tabs. https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/6650